# Ajax loading multiple times as well as script loading multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I asked half this question already but as i began debugging and messing around with code i noticed some other issues. On my website, http://www.yokaproject.com/, for arguments sake this is what i want you to do. Click on the art tab first, youll notice two logs to the console one for script length, other is ajax call, 5 and 1 respectively. I dont understand why it logs 5, i have 4 known scripts. Then click the next tab, music, it will log 8 twice for script length, and ajax call twice, why? Further it will keep adding in this pattern. I have this very simple request, please work with me on this. Im not saying write code for me or give me everything, just help direct me so i can actually learn my mistake and how to correct it. In fact i would even chat with someone and work on this issue, i just really want to write better JS. That being said here is my code(ignore my script check function meant to comment that out):

*This is just my ajax function, please check my website to see further details, http://www.yokaproject.com/index.html

```
function handlersAttached(){
  $('.header a').on('click', ajaxLoad);

}

handlersAttached();


function ajaxLoad(e) {
  console.log($("script").length);
  console.log("ajax called");
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var that = $(this);
    that.off('click'); // remove handler
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "html",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#container").html(data);
    })
};
```

Comment: Your ajax is loading full page full of scripts again

Comment: @charlietfl any suggestions on how i should go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

At the first click `$(scripts)` returned following tags:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/load_scripts.js"></script>
<script>/*google analytics stuff*/</script>
```

At the next one the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/load_scripts.js"></script>
<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/load_scripts.js"></script>
<script>/*google analytics stuff*/</script>
```

It seems that first three of them are appending to DOM tree every time your ajax call performed. Furthermore, `load_scripts.js` is among them itself, so next clicks will produce more ajax calls and more triggered handlers with `console.log` respectively.

Solution: do not include scripts in ajax response or, at least, do not append them to DOM tree. Depends on what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: interesting, quick question, would that be the reason why my content is constantly doubling? when you go from art tab, to any other tab, back to art tab it contantly doubles or adds the same content.

Comment: Yes, i bet that this happens exactly because of this.
After each click you have `$("#container").html(data);` executing several times because of appending `load_scripts.js` (which contains this html replace) on ajax call. So you have your content appended several times too.

Comment: thank you, im gonna mess around with this and get back to you